# FileSystemWatcher ChangedEvent wont fire for dll files

Tags: c#, dll, filter, filesystemwatcher

I have a service that monitors a directory for dll version changes. Funny thing is I used this exact code on another PC and it worked just fine. I removed the "*.dll" filter and then tried running it in search of all files (*.*) and it fires.. but that's not what I want. I want just Dll files. Not sure why this is not working..

```
FileSystemWatcher _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the service
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool Start()
        {

            var path = @"C:\Test";
            _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.Attributes;

            _watcher.Path = path;
            _watcher.Filter = "*.dll";
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            _watcher.Changed += _watcher_Changed;

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: out of curiousity: why would you monitor `NotifyFilters.Attributes;` if you are interested in *dll version changes*?

Comment: Doesn't the attributes of a file contain version? I know it works because I have a working model on another PC. The only thing that changed was the directory on a different computer. I have verified its pointing to the proper directory. I know its an issue with filter, because if I tell it to monitor all files, and then make a version change to the dll file, it picks it up and the event fires. It's only the *.dll filter that won't fire the event.

Comment: File attributes don't include version... They are hidden, archive,readonly,... See result of attrib command for given file.

Comment: That was the issue. I was wrong. Thanks.